# Mask images not displaying when used multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Background**

I am displaying **Mask image** in website  & told users to upload image....

[image]

Once user upload image, I am filling users uploaded image inside  mask image

[image]

Its working fine in [website](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/single.html) & in codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/wNqXEJ

**Requirement** :

Now  i am trying to upload two mask image , but this time mask images are not displaying as in codepen2 : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/OdjErW & in [website2](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/singlea.html)

**html**

```
<input type="file" id="fileupa" />
<input type="file" id="fileupb" />

<div class="minaimg masked-imga"   ondragover="onDragOver(event)"ondragover="onDragOver(event)" >
  <div draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" id="uploadedImg">
    <div class="minaimga">
      <!-- give an id for ease of selection -->
      <img id="target_img"  alt="">

      <div></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="minaimg masked-imgb"   ondragover="onDragOver(event)"ondragover="onDragOver(event)" >
  <div draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" id="uploadedImg">
    <div class="minaimgb">
      <!-- give an id for ease of selection -->
      <img id="target_img"  alt="">

      <div></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.masked-imga {

  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQpM4.png);
  mask-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQpM4.png);
  -webkit-mask-position: center center;
  mask-position: center center;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;  

  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.minaimga {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
}

.masked-imgb {

  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQpM4.png);
  mask-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQpM4.png);
  -webkit-mask-position: center center;
  mask-position: center center;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;  

  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.minaimgb {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
}
```

**script**

```
fileupa.onchange = e => {
 target_img.src = URL.createObjectURL(fileupa.files[0]);   
}

fileupb.onchange = e => {
 target_img.src = URL.createObjectURL(fileupb.files[0]);   
}

let prevX = 0, prevY = 0,translateX = 0, translateY = 0, scale = 1, zoomFactor = 0.1;

function onDragStart(evt) {
  if (evt.dataTransfer && evt.dataTransfer.setDragImage) {
evt.dataTransfer.setDragImage(evt.target.nextElementSibling, 0, 0);
  }
  prevX = evt.clientX;
  prevY = evt.clientY;
}

function onDragOver(evt) {
  translateX += evt.clientX - prevX;
  translateY += evt.clientY - prevY;
  prevX = evt.clientX;
  prevY = evt.clientY;
  updateStyle();
}

function updateStyle() 
{ 
let transform = "translate(" +translateX+ "px, "+ translateY + "px) scale("+scale+")"; 

if(document.querySelector('#uploadedImg img'))
document.querySelector('#uploadedImg img').style.transform = transform;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code you use same `id` on `img` tag  `target_img`. `IDs`are always unique.

**File upload A**

```
 <div class="minaimga">
          <!-- give an id for ease of selection -->
          <img id="target_imga"  alt="">

          <div></div>

        </div>
```

**File Upload B:**

```
<div class="minaimgb">
      <!-- give an id for ease of selection -->
      <img id="target_imgb"  alt="">

      <div></div>

    </div>
```

**[Working Demo](https://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/rPzroa)**

```
fileupa.onchange = e => {
 target_imga.src = URL.createObjectURL(fileupa.files[0]);   
}

fileupb.onchange = e => {
 target_imgb.src = URL.createObjectURL(fileupb.files[0]);   
}
```

You can assign `height` of  `.minaimga,.minaimgb` these two classes.

```
 .minaimga,.minaimgb {
      display: block;
      background-color: black;
      height:500px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, your code is working fine in [website](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/singled.html), but why mask images not displaying before i upload? but before when i used single mask image, it was displaying before  i upload as [here](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/single.html)

Comment: `.minaimga , .minaimgb` this two class to set `height`  to set mask image. check [CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/rPzroa) now

Answer (score -3):

You can not use an ID twice. IDs are always unique. You should use classes.

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you please tell which id you are talking about ? i am using two different ids - `fileupa` & `fileupb`.....